# How to get sp_execute handle sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a example for `sp_prepare` and `sp_execute`:

```sql
DECLARE @P1 int;  
EXEC sp_prepare @P1 output,   
    N'@Param int',  
    N'select @Param';  
SELECT @P1;  --@p1 = Handle

EXEC sp_execute @P1, 123; --result 123 
EXEC sp_execute @P1, 456; --result 456
```

How do I `query int handle(@P1)` to get select @Param sql after `sp_prepare`?

---

#### expected :

input handle

```
select * from someview(handle)
```

get output:

```
select @Param
```

Comment: @DaleK yes it's plan_handle that it's sp_prepare handle

Comment: `plan_handle` has nothing to do with `handle` - here is how you find a [`plan handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `So you called sp_prepare with a string containing an SQL statement?` yes @Dale K